# Are the integers definable in $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$?

Tags: logic, model-theory

I am familiar with the statement (not the proof) of Robinson's definition of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ in the language of rings. I would like to ask the same question for $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ in place of $\mathbb{Q}$ (again in $L_r$, the language of rings), where by $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ I mean the set of rationals with denominator coprime to $p$. 
As a second part, I would be interested to know whether a uniform definition exists. Let me also give some context: my initial question was whether $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is undecidable in $L_r$ and the most natural approach that came to my mind was to define the integers in there.

Comment: What is $\Bbb Z_{(p)}$? The $p$-adic integers? or the set of rationals with denominator coprime to $p$?

Comment: The latter, the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $(p)$.

Comment: Also, whenever you ask about definability in a structure, you should specify the language of the structure. Here you mean the language of rings $\{0,1,+,-,\times\}$, right?

Comment: The former should be $\Bbb Z_p$ (though many use that notation for $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$, sigh)

Comment: Yes, I mean the language of rings. I will edit my post to clarify all of these points.

Comment: I'd guess that with $\phi(r,y,z)\equiv \exists a\exists b\exists c(2+yzr^2=a^2+yb^2-zc^2)$ and $\theta(r,x,yz)\equiv (\phi(p+1,y,z)\land\forall w(\phi(w,y,z)\to \phi(w+1,y,z))\to \phi(r,y,z)$, we should have $r\in\Bbb Z\land r>p\iff \forall y\forall z\theta(r,y,z)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. One way to do it is to interpret $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, use Robinson's definition of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$, and then pull this set back into $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$. It may be that there's a more direct approach, but this way really only uses generalities about interpretations.

So first, note that we can define the set $Q = \{(x,y)\mid y\neq 0\}\subseteq (\mathbb{Z}_{(p)})^2$. Think of an element $(a,b)\in Q$ as a formal fraction $\frac{a}{b}$. Now there is a definable equivalence relation $\sim$ on $Q$ by $(a,b)\sim (c,d)$ iff $ad = bc$ expressing equality of fractions. And we can define $\sim$-classes $0_Q,1_Q$ and operations $+_Q,-_Q,\times_Q$ on $Q$ which respect by $\sim$ by the usual definitions of arithmetic with fractions. Then you can check that $(Q/{\sim};0_Q,1_Q,+_Q,-_Q,\times_Q)\cong (\mathbb{Q};0,1,+,-,\times)$.

Now take a formula $\varphi(x)$ in the language of rings defining $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$. Transform it into a formula $\varphi'(x,y)$ by replacing the symbols in the language of rings with their counterparts in $Q$, replacing $=$ by the definition of $\sim$, and replacing quantifiers by quantifiers over $Q$. Then $\varphi'(x,y)$ defines the isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ inside $Q/{\sim}$.

Finally, the natural inclusion $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ is given by $a\mapsto \frac{a}{1}$, so the formula $\varphi'(a,1)$ expresses that $\frac{a}{1}\in \mathbb{Z}$ and defines $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$.

Comment: $Q\subseteq\mathbb Z_{(p)}^2$, not $\mathbb Z_{(p)}$. This doesn't make any difference though.

Comment: @Wojowu yep, thanks for the correction.

Comment: Also note that in your last paragraph you use $\mathbb Z_p$ instead of $\mathbb Z_{(p)}$, twice.